# Extra Box Appears When Browser Ratio is Different

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to create a clickable box that sizes and positions relative to how the browser sizes, but I get an extra box when I decrease the width of the browser and increase the length. I'm not sure what is going on and how to get rid of it.

Here are screen captures of what is going on:
- Browser at full size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lorPW.png
- Browser stretched as described above: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbT0K.png

CSS:

```
img.banner {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0
}

#banner {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative
}

a.rollover {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 15%;
    width: 17%;
    height: 8%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="banner">
    <img src="image.png" class="banner"/>
    <a href="banner1.png" class="rollover">
</div>
</body>
```

Also, any other suggestions to improve my CSS and HTML is appreciated, since I'm new to this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you copy your code into a jsfiddle and post the link? Alternatively, do you have it hosted somewhere we can view? I would like to see what the generated code is when the browser is resized

Comment: I have uploaded the code here: https://github.com/jennc11/site.
I don't think it does that when I actually upload an image, instead of creating an empty box in CSS, so I can try that method. But it would be interesting to find out why it does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple though it seems, by not closing the anchor tag the browser is generating two anchors - one inside the div, and one outside it. These layout on top of each other until the browser is resized: then their positions deviate a bit and they 'split'. Fix by closing the anchor:

```
<body>
<div id="banner">
    <img src="image.png" class="banner"/>
    <a href="banner1.png" class="rollover"></a>     <--added closing tag here
</div>
</body>
```

You can [check out the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/katstevens/fpgNd/). Can't believe it took me so long!

Comment: Oh my! Thanks! I can't believe spent hours looking at it and missed that.